# How to release some resources automatically just before a widget is destroyed?

Tags: python, pyside

I would like to release some resources just before a widget is destroyed, but I don't want to do it manually(I have many widgets, each widget has its own resource). I hope the release function is automatically called when I close the whole GUI software, just like I can do it in each widget destruct function using c++. How can I do it?

**EDIT**:The main resource is QThread, whose event loop is started upon the widget constructed. I want to stop event loop before the widget is destroyed.

**EDIT**: As @mguijarr said, I connect widget destroyed signal to  resource release function, but it seems doesn't work:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'init MyWidget'
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.destroyed.connect(self.onDestroyed)

    def onDestroyed(self):
        print 'onDestroyed invoked'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle('Test')
    w.show()
    a.exec_()
    print 'app exit!'
```

when I start the app and then close it, the output is:

> init MyWidget
>
> app exit!

Comment: Python has a destructor `__del__(self)` but it is rarely used since there is garbage collection and the objects which don't have references anymore are purged automatically.

Comment: @Klaus D. That is the problem, python can't guarantee the 'destructor' to be called on time.

Comment: That is an other cause it is used rarely. Maybe you will get better help when you give more information on the background of your need for a descructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the `destroyed` signal from `QObject` base class of your
widgets to your own destructor-like function, there is a trick though:
the widget need to have the 'DeleteOnClose' attribute set:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'init MyWidget'
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ###
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.destroyed.connect(self.onDestroyed)
        ###
    def onDestroyed(self):
        print 'onDestroyed invoked'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle('Test')
    w.show()
    a.exec_()
    print 'app exit!
```

Output:

```
~% python /tmp/bla.py
init MyWidget
onDestroyed invoked
app exit!
```

Comment: Then when **destroyed** signal is emitted? I don't want to emit it manually.

Comment: It is emitted by any QObject

Comment: I tried it, as I updated the question, but it didn't work.

Comment: I guess you need to set the Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose flag to the widget: `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)`, I edited answer with fixed code sorry for the delay

Comment: I really appreciate your response. I don't know why, I can't reproduce your result. My environment is: win7, Python2.7.5,  Qt4.8.7. I copied your code and executed it in cmd console, but the result was the same as before.

Comment: try to add a `del a` after `a.exec_()` to force deletion instead of relying on garbage collector

Comment: I'm curious, did you manage to solve your problem? What was it?

Comment: As you said, I added `del a` after `a.exec_(`), but nothing changed, the result  was the same. And `del w` changed nothing either.